# flag immutable on flutter

Tags: android, flutter

I am facing a problem while trying to compile with android 31+. I am using mainly geolocator flutter dependency, but I can't find where the error comes from. I have tried to pass PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE to AndroidIntent but I get the same error. Is there a way to identify where the error is? This is the log:

```
Launching lib/main.dart on sdk gphone64 x86 64 in debug mode...
main.dart:1
✓  Built build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app-debug.apk.
E/AndroidRuntime(24077): FATAL EXCEPTION: pool-5-thread-1
E/AndroidRuntime(24077): Process: com.xxx.xxx, PID: 24077
E/AndroidRuntime(24077): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: com.xxx.xxx: Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE be specified when creating a PendingIntent.
E/AndroidRuntime(24077): Strongly consider using FLAG_IMMUTABLE, only use FLAG_MUTABLE if some functionality depends on the PendingIntent being mutable, e.g. if it needs to be used with inline replies or bubbles.
E/AndroidRuntime(24077):    at android.app.PendingIntent.checkPendingIntent(PendingIntent.java:428)
E/AndroidRuntime(24077):    at android.app.PendingIntent.getBroadcastAsUser(PendingIntent.java:731)
E/AndroidRuntime(24077):    at android.app.PendingIntent.getBroadcast(PendingIntent.java:718)
E/AndroidRuntime(24077):    at androidx.work.impl.utils.ForceStopRunnable.getPendingIntent(ForceStopRunnable.java:174)
E/AndroidRuntime(24077):    at androidx.work.impl.utils.ForceStopRunnable.isForceStopped(ForceStopRunnable.java:108)
E/AndroidRuntime(24077):    at androidx.work.impl.utils.ForceStopRunnable.run(ForceStopRunnable.java:86)
E/AndroidRuntime(24077):    at androidx.work.impl.utils.SerialExecutor$Task.run(SerialExecutor.java:75)
E/AndroidRuntime(24077):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
E/AndroidRuntime(24077):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:644)
E/AndroidRuntime(24077):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)
Exited (sigint)
```

Thanks.

Adding PendingIntent flag immutable to androidIntent constructor